# Using CNContactViewController without adding a contact (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift3, cncontact

I want to use contactsUI `CNContactViewController.init(forNewContact: a)` for view only and take the value to the server. However, right now the func also adding a contact to addressbook/contact app, is it possible to prevent this?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @beseder When we use contactViewController delegate, we get the CNcontact right after we click done, so I get the identifier from that cncontact and delele it. Use ForNewContact -> done -> send its data to our server/app -> delete the contact from ios contact programmatically

Comment: Thanks! That is what I also ended with meanwhile :-) But it feels bad ... And most of all: It needs write access to the user's contacts, which I in fact do NOT need. So the `contactStore` property of `CNContactViewController` does not behave as documented, right?

Comment: Did you at any point found a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Contacts Framework Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Contacts/Reference/Contacts_Framework/

> sample: ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import ContactsUI

class ViewController: UIViewController, CNContactPickerDelegate {

let contactPickerViewController = CNContactPickerViewController()
@IBOutlet var titleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var valueLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    contactPickerViewController.delegate = self
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func touchUpInside(sender: UIButton) {
    self.presentViewController(contactPickerViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func contactPicker(picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelectContactProperty contactProperty: CNContactProperty) {

    titleLabel.text = ""
    valueLabel.text = ""

    if let label = contactProperty.label {
        titleLabel.text = CNLabeledValue.localizedStringForLabel(label)
    }

    if let phone = contactProperty.value as? CNPhoneNumber {
        valueLabel.text = phone.stringValue
    }

    if let stringData = contactProperty.value as? String {
        valueLabel.text = stringData
    }

    if let adress = contactProperty.value as? CNPostalAddress {
        let adressString = adress.street + " " + adress.city + " " + adress.country + " " + adress.postalCode
        valueLabel.text = adressString
    }

}
}
```

download project files: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yqdhqld0osp508b/Archive.zip?dl=0

Comment: This solution helped?